# Does zero distributional derivative imply constant function?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

If a real function $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and its derivative $f'$ is zero, then $f$ is constant. Does this result still hold when $f$ has a *weak* derivative?

Explicitly, suppose $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function such that its distributional derivative $Df$ is zero. Does this mean that $f$ is constant?

Comment: Have you tried invoking the definition of distributional derivative?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/147748 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28018/

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118525/a-sufficient-condition-for-a-function-to-be-of-class-c2-in-the-weak-sense/120894#120894

Answer (score 1):

The following corollary of the celebrated Du Boys-Reymond Lemma holds true.

**Corollary.** If $u \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(a,b)$ is such that $$\int_a^b u(x) \varphi'(x)\, dx=0$$ for every $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(a,b)$, then $u$ is almost everywhere constant.

I wrote the statement of B. Dacorogna, *Introduction au calcul des variations*.