# If $-\Delta u=f$ in the distributional sense, can we conclude that $\int_Λ(-\Delta u)v\:{\rm d}λ=\int_Λfv\:{\rm d}λ$ for all $v\in H^1(\Lambda)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, calculus-of-variations, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$
- $f\in L^2(\Lambda)$

Assume $$-\Delta u=f\tag 1$$ in the sense of distributions. Why can we conclude that $$\int_\Lambda(-\Delta u)v\:{\rm d}\lambda=\int_\Lambda fv\:{\rm d}\lambda\tag 2$$ for all $v\in H^1(\Lambda)$.

I've read that in a [lecture note](https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/~ledret/M1English/M1ApproxPDE_Chapter3.pdf) (see page 78) and don't understand this. Clearly, the claim would be true for $v\in H_0^1(\Lambda)$. Maybe they use an approximation argument that I'm not aware of (with that in mind, please feel free to add any regularity assumption on $\Lambda$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the regularity of $u$. For $u\in H^2$,
$$-\Delta u=f\quad\text{in}\quad\mathcal{D}'(\Lambda)\tag{#}$$
means
$$\int_\Lambda(-\Delta u)\varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_\Lambda f\varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda\quad\forall\ \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\Lambda)$$
which implies
$$-\Delta u=f\quad\text{a.e.}\tag{$*$}$$
by the [du Bois-Reymond Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations#Multivariable_functions). Multiplying $(*)$ by $v\in H^1(\Lambda)$ and integrating over $\Lambda$ you get the result <s>(without any further regularity on $\Lambda$)</s>.

---

### Edit

Let $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be open and $f,u\in L^1 _{\text{loc}}(\Lambda)$. The distributions $f$, $u$ and $\Delta u$ are defined by
$$\langle f,\varphi\rangle=\int_\Lambda f\varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda,\quad \langle u,\varphi\rangle=\int_\Lambda u\varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda,\quad \langle\Delta u,\varphi\rangle=\langle u,\Delta\varphi\rangle=\int_\Lambda u\Delta \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda,\quad\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\Lambda).$$
Assume that $u,f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Lambda)$ and $-\Delta u=f$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\Lambda)$. Then
$$-\int_\Lambda u\Delta \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_\Lambda f \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$

If, additionally, $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$ and $\Lambda$ is bounded with Lipschitz boundary, then (Corollary 3.46 [here](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/LEHRE/NUM_PDE_FUB/num_pde_fub_3.pdf))
$$\int_\Lambda (-\Delta u) \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda=-\int_\Lambda u\Delta \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_\Lambda f \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$
Therefore by the Du Bois Reymond Lemma (Lema 1.16 [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Qiy8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%22Du+bois+reymond+lemma%22+L%5Ep&source=bl&ots=KgNL8O-5NO&sig=KYDuYAZudTxwX-N954DGal0bvdo&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg1s-GpYbRAhXMkZAKHav0BcQQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=%22Du%20bois%20reymond%27s%20lemma%22&f=false))
$$-\Delta u=f\quad\text{a.e.}$$

**Conclusion:** $(\#)$ implies that
$$\int_\Lambda(-\Delta u)v\;\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_\Lambda fv$$
for all $v\in H^1(\Lambda)$ provided that $\Lambda$ is a bounded open set with Lipschitz boundary and $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$.

---

### Edit 2

Print of the third link:

[image]

Comment: 1. So, your statement is true for any open $\Lambda$? Or do we need boundedness too? 2. For $(\ast)$, it's sufficient that $u$ has a weak Laplacian $\Delta u\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Lambda)$. So, the statement should be true for more general $u$ which don't necessarily belong to $H^2(\Lambda)$. Is it true for even more general $u$?

Comment: Or do you exploit $H^2(\Lambda)\subseteq C^0(\overline\Lambda)$? I guess you do that in the invocation of the Lemma? In that case, the statement is true only when $d<4$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d We need $u$ and $\Lambda$ regular enough so that we can apply integration by parts and the Du Bois Reymond Lemma. For the first, the basic assumptions are $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$ and $\Lambda$ bounded with Lipschitz boundary (see Corollary 3.46 [here](http://migre.me/vM820)); for the second, the basic assumptions are $\Lambda$ open and $u$ locally integrable (see Lema 1.16 [here](http://migre.me/vM80I)). As the Du Bois-Reymond Lemma is very general, the key point is the needed assumptions for the integration by parts. See the edit in my answer. No, I didn't exploit the said embedding.

Comment: It should be $$\color{red}{-}\int_\Lambda u\Delta \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_\Lambda f \varphi\;\mathrm{d}\lambda$$ in your second centered equation of your edit.

Comment: Your link to Lemma 1.16 is not working.

Comment: Suppose $p\in H^1(\Lambda)$ and $f\in L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ with $$\langle\nabla\phi,\nabla p\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\langle\nabla\phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda)\;.\tag 3$$ Can we conclude $\nabla p=f$ a.e. by the du Bois-Reymond Lemma too?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I have corrected the signs and added a print of the link.

Comment: @0xbadf00d For your last question, let us consider the case $d=1$. Then $(3)$ reduces to $$\langle\partial_x\phi,\partial_x p\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\langle\partial_x\phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\forall\ \phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda)$$
By [this corollary of the Du Bois-Reymond Lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/163321/70305) we can conclude that there exists a consatnt $c$ (not necessarily zero) such that $\nabla p=f+c$ a.e. For $d>1$, is not clear for me what do you mean by $\langle\nabla \phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}$ and $\nabla p=f$.

Comment: Why it's not clear for you what $\langle\nabla \phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}$ is? $\nabla\phi=(\partial_{x_1}\phi,\ldots,\partial_{x_d}\phi)^T$ is the gradient of $\phi$ and it's clear that it belongs to $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. $\nabla p=f$ (in $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$) would perfectly make sense.

Comment: Let me remark that [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068665/does-the-solution-of-my-variational-problem-satisfy-a-specific-neumann-boundary) is the reason for my last question here. I hope that I can show that the solution $p$ of $(3)$ (in the other question) satisfies $γ_\nu\nabla p=γ_\nu u$ which should be the case, if I could show that $\langle∇q,\nabla p\rangle_{L^2(Λ,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\langle∇q, u\rangle_{L^2(Λ,\:\mathbb R^d)}$ for all $q\in W$. EDIT: In the previous statement, I assume that the given $u\in L^2(Λ,\mathbb R^d)$ satisfies $\nabla\cdot u\in L^2(Λ)$.